# Can CodeIgniter Website be deployed to Cloud Hosting?

Tags: cloud-hosting, cloud, codeigniter

Currently I'm thinking of making a website in CodeIgniter and planning to deploy it in cloud hosting but I don't know if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for installing CodeIgnitor](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/installation/installing_manual.html) says:

> Download the latest version, and extract it to become your project root.

That is certainly something that con be done on cloud hosting.

It sounds like you don't know what cloud hosting is. Cloud hosting is very similar to getting a dedicated server or a VPS:

- You get ssh access to a machine running an operating system of your choosing.
- You are responsible for installing all your own software
- You can usually install anything you can install on any other headless computer over ssh

The differences of cloud computing compared to dedicated servers or a VPS are in how the resources are allocated and priced:

- You use a web interface or API to create and manage new servers
- Billing is typically done per hour rather than per month

Given how much cloud instances look like more traditional servers, there is no reason you can't put CodeIgnitor on them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that for sure. You just have to deploy the public folder or you can just execute spark(startup manager for ci4) if you are using VPS.